# Forbidden access by Azure Functions to API

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Here is the code of my Azure function created in Azure portal:

```
#r "D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTriggerCSharp1\bin\MobileWebAPI.dll"
using System.Net;
using MobileWebAPI.Controllers;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    PayslipListController.NotifyUsersWithNewPayroll();
}
```

Error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. System:
>   Unable to connect to the remote server. System: An attempt was made to
>   access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions to IP
>   host.

The method `NotifyUsersWithNewPayroll` is calling a `POST API`.

Comment: is it working locally ? where do you store the API url to call ? Did you add it to the app settings blade in the portal ?

Comment: Could you share code of `NotifyUsersWithNewPayroll` method? I am not sure it's Function's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Already fix the issue. See code below.

```
#r "D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTriggerCSharp1\bin\MobileWebAPI.dll"
using System.Net;
using MobileWebAPI.Controllers;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    PayslipListController.NotifyUsersWithNewPayroll();
    //log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");


}
```